# How to insert data into Azure Synapse Database with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, azure-synapse

I'm trying to insert some rows into a Synapse Database using SQLAlchemy. However I'm getting this error when doing db.session.commit():

```
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,200 - Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,209 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,210 -     self.dialect.do_execute(
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,212 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,213 -     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,215 - pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parse error at line: 1, column: 58: Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'. (103010) (SQLExecDirectW)")
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,216 -
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,218 - The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,236 - Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,246 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py", line 672, in error_router
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,251 -     return self.handle_error(e)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,255 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,268 -     rv = self.dispatch_request()
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,280 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,285 -     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,293 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py", line 405, in wrapper
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,306 -     resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,320 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 107, in view
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,324 -     return current_app.ensure_sync(self.dispatch_request)(**kwargs)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,333 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/resource.py", line 46, in dispatch_request
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,339 -     resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,344 -   File "/code/app/main/util/decorators.py", line 53, in decorated_function
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,347 -     return f(*args, **kwargs)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,353 -   File "/code/app/main/controller/front_controller.py", line 205, in post
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,363 -     return createUser(request)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,370 -   File "/code/app/main/service/front_service.py", line 459, in createUser
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,373 -     db.session.commit()
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,383 -   File "<string>", line 2, in commit
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,386 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1451, in commit
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,389 -     self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,400 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 829, in commit
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,413 -     self._prepare_impl()
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,419 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,429 -     self.session.flush()
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,433 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3383, in flush
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,435 -     self._flush(objects)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,438 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3523, in _flush
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,444 -     transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,447 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,450 -     compat.raise_(
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,466 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,478 -     raise exception
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,485 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3483, in _flush
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,489 -     flush_context.execute()
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,506 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,511 -     rec.execute(self)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,513 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 630, in execute
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,515 -     util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,516 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,528 -     _emit_insert_statements(
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,542 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1238, in _emit_insert_statements
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,548 -     result = connection._execute_20(
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,554 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1705, in _execute_20
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,564 -     return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,566 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 333, in _execute_on_connection
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,569 -     return connection._execute_clauseelement(
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,571 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1572, in _execute_clauseelement
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,577 -     ret = self._execute_context(
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,588 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1943, in _execute_context
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,600 -     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,610 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2124, in _handle_dbapi_exception
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,618 -     util.raise_(
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,634 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,642 -     raise exception
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,647 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,649 -     self.dialect.do_execute(
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,652 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,654 -     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,668 - sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parse error at line: 1, column: 58: Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'. (103010) (SQLExecDirectW)")
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,685 - [SQL: INSERT INTO dbo.users ([user], password, role_id, email) OUTPUT inserted.user_id VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,694 - [parameters: ('user', '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99', 24, 'email')]
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,697 - (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

This is the SQL script I used to create the table in Synapse:

```
CREATE TABLE [users] (
   [user_id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED NOT ENFORCED,
   [user] VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
   [password] VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
   [role_id] INT NOT NULL,
   [email] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

This is the SQLAlchemy model of that table:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'mssql'
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('user_id', mssql_clustered=False),
        {"schema": BaseModel.__table_args__["schema"]},    
    )
```

And this is the code that I'm running to insert the data into de DB:

```
        user = User(
            user = data["user"], 
            password = hashlib.md5(data["password"].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(),
            role_id = role.role_id,
            email = data["email"]
            )
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
```

Did anyone else came across this error? I really need some help because I don't see that much documentation about SQLAlchemy with Synapse specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says the schema as dbo

```
ERROR - 2023-02-01 15:24:28,685 - [SQL: INSERT INTO **dbo**.users ([user], password, role_id, email) OUTPUT inserted.
```

but your create table says the schema is test

```
CREATE TABLE **[test]**.[users]
```

Comment: Oh, I copied the wrong sql script. I will edit it